# General container in ANSI C

Tags: c

For several reasons that are not important for this question, is it possible to implement a list - a container - for a general struct in ANSI? Can this same list contains structs of different types?

EDIT: after several suggestions, I'm considering some of the options. But it's still not clear for me why there is no standard way to do this. Is it not necessary in ANSI C? The only way to do it is to use another language?

Cheers

Comment: You can probably find your answer on this very site with a bit of searching. I know I've seen the question several times.

Comment: Pointers are your only option here, without some preprocessor voodoo.

Comment: chris, I searched here and google, and couldn't find a definitive answer. I appreciate if you could point me to one of the questions

Comment: Are you *sure* the reasons are not important for this question?

Comment: I'd bet money that the reasons are important for this question.

Comment: let's bet! :-) I have to develop a scientific code that will run on a supercomputer, and it will have to include CUDA parts. I have a working Python code for the same problem, but so far it has proven to be CUDA-resistant. So I was tasked of implementing the same algorithm in pristine ANSI C. Otherwise, not really relevant to the problem. Do I win the bet? :-D

Comment: So, Step 1: Python Step 2: Generic C container Step 3: Science!... I think there is something missing between step 2 and step 3. Suppose you had this container of `StructA`'s and some `StructB`'s. What would you then do with it? You couldn't iterate because you don't know if you will be getting an A or a B (Or maybe you do want to do this, which is important to the question). What do you actually want to do with the things in the container?

Comment: I would put several instantes of structA and structB in a list, and call some functions over all the elements of the list, that would have to give different answers depending if it's a structA or structB. BTW, if this question is not worth asking (-2 in rating), where is a good answer? Or the best answer is "use another language"?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do, it's *possible*.  It's a major pain in the ass, but it's possible.

You can use `void` pointers to create a generic list, such as

```
struct glist {
  void *data;
  stuct glist *next;
};
```

The `data` member can point to objects of any type.  The problem is, you lose that type information once you assign the pointer; you need to keep track of the type separately.  You can either use an integer or enumeration value to tag the type, such as

```
enum dtype {type_A, type_B, type_C, ...};

struct glist {
  void *data;
  enum dtype data_type;
  struct glist *next;
};
```

or

```
#define TYPE_A 1
#define TYPE_B 2
...
struct glist {
  void *data;
  int data_type;
  struct glist *next;
};
```

When you retrieve the element from the list, you'd check the `data_type` member to determine which functions to call or what procedures to execute based on the data type:

```
switch (elem->data_type)
{
  case TYPE_A: // process for TYPE A
    break;

  case TYPE_B: // process for TYPE B
    break;

  ...
}
```

Alternately, you can store a pointer to one or more functions that operate on that particular data type and skip the switch or if-else statements altogether:

```
struct glist {
  void *data;
  void (*process)(const void *);
  void (*copy)(const void *);
  void (*delete)(const void *); // not shown
  struct glist *next;
};
```

For each data type, you create an instance of a process function and tie a pointer to that function to the node.  The function has to take a `void *` as input, but it will convert to the appropriate type to do the processing:

```
void process_typeA (const void *data)
{
  typeA *obj = (typeA *) data; // cast away const
  // process obj as necessary
}

void *copy_typeA (const void *data)
{
  typeA *obj = (typeA *) data;
  typeA *newObj = malloc(sizeof *newObj);
  if (newObj)
    // copy from obj to newObj
  return newObj;
}

void addItem (struct glist *list, const void *obj, 
              void (*process)(const void *), 
              void *(*copy)(consg void *),
              void (*delete)(const void *))
{
  struct glist *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
  newNode->copy = copy;
  newNode->delete = delete;
  newNode->process = process;
  newNode->data = (*copy)(obj);
  newNode->next = NULL;

  // add newNode to list 
}

void foo(void)
{
  struct glist *myList = new_list(); // not shown here
  ...
  addItem(myList, myTypeAObj, process_typeA, copy_typeA, delete_typeA);
  addItem(myList, myTypeBObj, process_typeB, copy_typeB, delete_typeB);
  ...
}
```

Then as you walk through the list, you can call the `process` function that's appropriate for that particular node:

```
void processList(struct glist *list)
{
  struct glist *node = list;
  while (node)
  {
    node->process(node->data);
    node = node->next;
  }
  ...
}
```

The beauty of this method is that you associate the behavior for that node with the node itself; you don't need to keep adding cases to a switch or if-else chain.  The drawback is that you're mucking around with a *lot* of pointers, you have to implement a separate process/copy/delete function for each data type you want to work with, you're doing non-trivial amounts of memory management (you *need* the copy and delete methods, for reasons that are obvious once you think about it), and you're throwing any notion of type safety out the window and into oncoming traffic; you lose any compiler-level protection against associating the wrong process/copy/delete function with the wrong data type.

Comment: Very complicated, but very powerful! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on the Linux Kernel Linked List. (http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/ has some info)

It can store arbitrary structs, but I believe only one type in a given list. It has been awhile since I have used it so I am a little rusty on the details. And as Richard alludes to, it uses some preprocessor voodoo, but not too much.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob Navia has this plan for "[The C Containers library project](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/ccl/ccl.html)".

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at sglib?

http://sglib.sourceforge.net/